# My Glide RecyclerView works in a ViewPager but not in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a RecyclerView I've been using for so long which uses Glide. Due to the increasing number of categories in my app and for QOL reasons, I've decided to switch to Navigation Drawer. However, the images I loaded to Glide won't display on the Navigation Drawer fragment, unlike in a ViewPager.

The Navigation Drawer Main Activity is a menu inside the MainActivity

Folder Structure

```
com.my.app
--MainActivity
--NavDrawerMainActivity
--DialogFragment
com.my.app.ui.home
--HomeFragment
--HomeRecyclerAdapter
```

NavDrawerMainActivity

```
package com.my.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.my.app.databinding.ActivityNavDrawerMainBinding

class NavDrawerMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityNavDrawerMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityNavDrawerMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarNavDrawerMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarNavDrawerMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_nav_gl_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_gl_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_nav_gl_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

HomeFragment

```
package com.my.app.ui.gl

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.my.app.GlideApp
import com.my.app.DialogFragment
import com.my.app.R
import com.my.app.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

private const val TAG = "HomeFragment"

class HomeFragment : Fragment(), HomeRecyclerAdapter.OnHomeListener  {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    lateinit var adapter: HomeRecyclerAdapter
    private val imageList = ArrayList<Int>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_01)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_02)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_03)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_04)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_05)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_06)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_07)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_08)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_09)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_10)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_11)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_12)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_13)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_14)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_15)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_16)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_17)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_18)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_19)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_20)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_21)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_22)
        imageList.add(R.drawable.ao03s2018_23)

        /*        adapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(this, imageList)*/
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(GlideApp.with(this), imageList, this)

    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            return HomeFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onHomeClick(position: Int) {

        val nextFrag = DialogFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("image", imageList[position])
        nextFrag.arguments = bundle

        nextFrag.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "onHomeClick")

        Log.d(TAG, "onHomeClick : ${imageList[position]}")
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Dialog Fragment

```
package com.my.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.my.app.databinding.DialogFragmentBinding

private const val TAG : String = "ImageViewerActivity"

class DialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private val binding by viewBinding(DialogFragmentBinding::bind)

    var image : Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //isCancelable = false
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.DialogTheme
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val requestOptions = RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

        val bundle = this.arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            val image = bundle.getInt("image", 0)

            Log.d(TAG, "DialogFragment >> image: $image")

            GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(image)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(binding.imageViewer)

        }
    }
}
```

HomeRecyclerAdapter

```
package com.my.app.ui.gl

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.my.app.R
import com.my.app.databinding.RecyclerAdapterHomeBinding

class HomeRecyclerAdapter(private val glide: RequestManager,
                          private val images: ArrayList<Int>,
                          private var onHomeListener: OnHomeListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ImageHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ImageHolder {
        return ImageHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_adapter_home, parent, false),
            onHomeListener
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageHolder, position: Int) {
        val path: Int = images[position]

        val requestOptions = RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

        glide.load(path)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(holder.homeImageView)
    }

    class ImageHolder(
        view: View,
        private var onHomeListener: OnHomeListener
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view),
        View.OnClickListener {

        val binding = RecyclerAdapterHomeBinding.bind(view)

        val homeImageView : ImageView = binding.imageView

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onHomeListener.onHomeClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    interface OnHomeListener {
        fun onHomeClick(position : Int)
    }
}
```